# Can i select a region of screen to take a screenshot of?

Tags: windows-10, screenshot

in windows 10, i can take a screenshot of the whole screen by hitting `Windows key + PrintScreen key`.

Can I select a region of screen to take a screenshot of?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can potentially do two things:  you can crop-down the full sized screen shot, or you can utilize the `Alt + PrintScrn` combo to take a screen shot of the window that specifically has attention.

Comment: `Alt + PrintScrn` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Doesn't Win 10 have the famous Snipping Tool which Win 7 .. 8 have on board? It lets you select regions.

Comment: If you ensure that you click on the window that you want to use for a screen shot, `Alt + PrintScrn` should capture it.  For example, if you open the `Disk Defragmenter` utility, select the window, and then `Alt + PrintScrn` will capture it on the clipboard.

Comment: If you want a bit more flexibility than the Snipping Tool, give Greenshot a try. Its open source, and one of the best screen capture utilities out there. Has support for screenshotting an area with zoom and magnification, you can use its editor to add text, lines, etc to it and even move the mouse pointer while inside. It can capture directly to clipboard, a file, to the internet, and many other things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Snipping Tool is a part of Windows. Works great with a easy to use drop down menu. Just type the word snip from the Start Menu. Select the area you want and save as .jpg or whatever you like.

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

This command blur the entire screen and you can select any rectangular region of the screen. Once selected, it is saved into clipboard so you can paste it anywhere. If you change your mind, just press <kbd>ESC</kbd>.